# Prototype mismatch: sub main::any: none vs (&@) at Exporter.pm

Tags: perl, any, subroutine-prototypes

```
use Dancer2;
use List::Util qw(any);

sub use_any_subroutine {

    foreach my $foo (@$foo_array) {
        next unless any { $_ == $foo->id } @hello_world;
    }    
    return;
}
```

there is a conflict with using List::Util and throwing a warning

**Prototype mismatch: sub main::any: none vs (&@) at Exporter.pm(...).**

i found a solution that is we can use `List::Util::any` instead of importing it before use,but i want to import it once,so how to avoid this warning

Thanks very much for comments.

Comment: Interesting enough, I get _Overwriting existing sub 'main::any' with sub 'any' exported by List::MoreUtils_ from my Perl 5.20.1. Which Perl version is this?

Comment: ahh, yes @simbabque you're right, i am also getting _Prototype mismatch: sub main::any: none vs (&@) at Exporter.pm(...)._  for `use List::Util qw(any);` and  _Overwriting existing sub 'main::any' with sub 'any' exported by List::MoreUtils_ for using `use List::MoreUtils qw(any);`

Comment: @Luna: Which version of Perl are you running please? Use `perl -v` to find out.

Comment: @Borodin - i am using perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [Dancer2](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2) and [List::MoreUtils](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) export an `any` function into your namespace.

For Dancer2, it's part of its DSL and is used as a route definition that matches any HTTP verb on incoming requests.

> Defines a route for multiple HTTP methods at once

The List::MoreUtils one is like a `grep` instead.

> Returns a true value if any item in LIST meets the criterion given through BLOCK.

The warning you are seeing is because you have imported [the Dancer2 one](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer2/lib/Dancer2/Manual.pod#any) first, so Perl learned about the prototype of that one. Then you imported [the one from List::MoreUtils](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#any-BLOCK-LIST), which overwrote `&main::any` in your namespace `main::`, but the prototype is still there.

You can avoid importing `any` from Dancer2.

```
use Dancer2 qw( !any );
use List::MoreUtils qw( any );

get '/' => sub {
    my @foo = ( 1, 2, 3 );
    return List::MoreUtils::any { $_ == 2 } @foo;
};

dance;
```

Or you can avoid importing `any` from List::MoreUtils (using `List::MoreUtils::any` instead of `any`).

```
use Dancer2;
use List::MoreUtils qw( );

get '/' => sub {
    my @foo = ( 1, 2, 3 );
    return List::MoreUtils::any { $_ == 2 } @foo;
};

dance;
```

Comment: Hmm. A Dancer expert to the rescue! I had no idea that it did that, but if Dancer uses Exporter as normal then you can `use Dancer '!any'` to avoid importing that symbol.

Comment: @Borodin I'll check how it does that. But OP might need the `any` keyword from Dancer2's DSL. And it would make it a hell of a lot harder to maintain to mix those two together. And I still cannot reproduce the error. Mine just complains and works.

Comment: @Borodin it's using Import::Into, not Exporter. But it does work with `use Dancer2 '!any'`. Please note that _Dancer_ and _Dancer2_ are completely different projects though.

Comment: @simbabque: what if i don't use `require List::MoreUtils;` ? because it works without any warning 
`use Dancer2;

sub use_any_subroutine {

    foreach my $foo (@$foo_array) {
        next unless List::MoreUtils::any  { $_ == $foo->id } @hello_world;
    }    
    return;
}`

Comment: @Luna then some other part of your code has already loaded List::MoreUtils and that's because it already knows about that package. But you shouldn't do that. You should always declare all your package's dependencies in your current package. Never rely on something else loading something you need. The `require` will simply not do anything if it's already loaded the module before.

Comment: no, you should not change use to require, you should just do `use List::MoreUtils ();`

Comment: @Luna, That would likely mean that you're calling Dancer's `any` instead of List::MoreUtils, which will give you the wrong result!

Comment: The answer needless switched to loading List::MoreUtils at runtime instead of compile-time. I changed answer to continue loading List::MoreUtils at runtime, which fixed problems the change introduced.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few possible solutions

Note that I'm using the core `List::Util` module here, because it also contains an `any` function, and shouldn't need installing on most recent releases of perl

- As you have said yourself, you could fully-qualify the subroutine instead of importing it, and use `List::Util::any`
- You could disable the import of `any` from `Dancer2` by using

  ```
  use Dancer2 '!any'
  ```

  which will work as long as you never need Dancer2's `any` to write your code
- You could also use `first` instead of `any` from `List::Util`, which returns the first element of the list for which the block returns a *true* value, and will work fine as long as everything in your list is *true*
- Another alternative is to import `any` from `List::Util` with a different name

  ```
  BEGIN {
      require List::Util;
      *my_any = \&List::Util::any;
  }
  ```

  and now you have a subroutine `my_any` that behaves exactly as the original `any` from `List::Util` but doesn't clash with the operator of the same name from `Dancer2`

Comment: The last suggestion is nice. I believe there is something on CPAN that does that for you. There is [as](http://p3rl.org/as), which makes long module names shorter, but I'm not sure it can alias function names.

Comment: The hacker keyboard is useful indeed.

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible to be sure without seeing more of your program, but at a guess, you have declared your own subroutine `sub any` as well as trying to import it from `List::MoreUtils`.

You need only the `use` statement.

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence in your answer.

Comment: no @Borodin, i am not declaring my own subroutine, in that case i would get _Subroutine any redefined at .._  warning.

Comment: @simbabque: I meant just that the program needs to contain only `use List::MoreUtils 'any'` and any other declaration is unnecessary.

Comment: @Luna: I carefully used *declared* and not *defined*. If you write `sub any` (a declaration) and then `use List::MoreUtils 'any'` then you will see the warning `Prototype mismatch: sub main::any: none vs (&@)` that you reported.

Comment: @Borodin aah i got you now, sorry i am newbie to perl